# Anagram function returns False for unknown reason in some words - Python

Tags: python, anagram

I've tried to create a function that returns True if two words are anagrams (have the same letters) to each other.

I realized that my counter counts to 13 but not sure what is the issue.

```
def is_anagram (worda: str , wordb: str) -> bool:
    count_same_letters = 0
    if len(worda) == len(wordb):
        for i in worda:
            for j in wordb:
                if i == j:
                    count_same_letters = count_same_letters+1
                    print(count_same_letters)
                    print(len(wordb))
        return count_same_letters == len(wordb)
    else:
        return False

print(is_anagram("anagram","nagaram"))
```

while trying the string 'abc' abd 'bca' the output was True as I expected, but the strings 'anagram' and 'nagaram'returns False

Comment: Your code has counted the same letter multiple times.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned, the problem here is that letters occurring more than once are counted again. Supposing you need to implement the algorithm yourself without `Count`, here's one approach to the problem:

```
def is_anagram (worda: str , wordb: str) -> bool:
    if len(worda) == len(wordb):
        remaining_letters = wordb
        for letter in worda:
            letter_index = remaining_letters.find(letter)
            if letter_index == -1:
                return False # no! not anagram
            
            remaining_letters = remaining_letters[:letter_index] + remaining_letters[letter_index+1:]
        
        if len(remaining_letters) == 0:
            return True
    else:
        return False
                
print(is_anagram("anagram", "gramnaa"))
print(is_anagram("omg", "omggg"))
print(is_anagram("abc", "cba"))
print(is_anagram("aaaa", "aaaaaa"))
```

By "deleting" every letter we find from `remaining_letters` our code will have to search through a smaller string on each iteration, possibly making it perform faster then some other alternatives.

Comment: Will not recommend this approach.  Because The running time of this program is O(n^2) as the find method is called within a loop. The find method has a linear time complexity, so calling it n times results in a quadratic running time. However, the worst-case running time is actually O(n^3) because the string concatenation!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your code has counted the same letter multiple times.  Try to run your code here - https://pythontutor.com/  and see each step-by-step the *counts*.

You could simplify it by using **collections.Counter()** in **standard** **lib** to make the faster counts and compare with each letters.  (*why reinvent the wheel?)*

```py
def is_anagram(str1, str2):
    a = str1.lower()        # if don't care case, can skip these steps
    b = str2.lower()
    
    return Counter(a) == Counter(b)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    string1 = 'funeral'
    string2 = 'realFun'

    print(is_anagram('anagram', 'nagaram'))   # True

    print(is_anagram(string1, string2))       # True
    print(is_anagram('abbac', 'cbbac'))       # False
```

If you really don't want to use collections.Counter(), here is plain *sort* to solve it:

This is still performing better than original code in O(nlogn).

```py
def is_anagram(worda: str, wordb: str) -> bool:
    if len(worda) != len(wordb):
        return False
    #sorted_a = sorted(worda)         #  this's for demo purpose only
    #sorted_b = sorted(wordb)

    return sorted(worda) == sorted(wordb)   

print(is_anagram("anagram", "gramnaa"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going through each pair of letters.

For instance if you have two 5-letter words, you're going through 25 pairs of letters. If you input `aaaab` and `baaaa`, your `count_same_letters` counter will get to `4*4 + 1*1` (4*4 pairs of `a`'s and 1*1 pairs of `b`'s).

Change your algorithm.